# Latin hyphenation and macrons (in ConTeXt, but I believe also in LaTeX)

Tags: context, hyphenation, macron

It seems that there are some problems for (Con)TeX(t) when hyphenating macronized words. When I inspect the ConTeXt language-file for Latin (http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/languages-mkiv.pdf), it tells TeX that ē=e, and so on. Here is a MWE with a very small textwidth, so many hyphenations.

```
 \setuplayout
[width=40mm]
\mainlanguage[la]
\language[la]
\setuphyphenation[method=traditional]
\setuptolerance[horizontal,strict] %zorgt voor minder overfull boxes
\definefontfeature
  [default][default]
  [protrusion=quality,
   expansion=quality]
\starttext
Vulpēs, quae per silvam errat et cibum quaerit, eum aspicit. Cāseum quoque videt. Eum ā corvō capere et ipsa ēsse vult. Ergō sē occultat inter folia, quae sunt in iīs rāmīs, quī nōn procul ā terrā absunt. Nam ā corvō vidērī nōn vult.
Vulpēs sē nōn movet, sed tantum verba facit: ''Ō corve, quam fōrmōsa est cauda tua, quam pulchrae sunt ālae! Ostende mihi ālās tuās!'' Corvus, quī ea vērba audit, dēlectātur et sē vertit et circumspicit.

\color[red]{same text, now without macrons, see the difference:}

Vulpes, quae per silvam errat et cibum quaerit, eum aspicit. Caseum quoque videt. Eum a corvo capere et ipsa esse vult. Ergo se occultat inter folia, quae sunt in iis ramis, qui non procul a terra absunt. Nam a corvo videri non vult.
Vulpes se non movet, sed tantum verba facit: ''O corve, quam formosa est cauda tua, quam pulchrae sunt alae! Ostende mihi alas tuas!'' Corvus, qui ea verba audit, delectatur et se vertit et circumspicit.
    \stoptext
```

Why does the hyphenation before or after a macronized vowel not happen?

---

Better MWE:

```
\language[la]
\setuphyphenation[method=traditional]
\starttext
\startlines
\hyphenatedword{vidērī}
\hyphenatedword{videri}
\hyphenatedword{Vulpēs}
\hyphenatedword{Vulpes}
\hyphenatedword{Cāseum}
\hyphenatedword{Caseum}
\hyphenatedword{vidērīvulpēscāseum}
\hyphenatedword{viderivulpescaseum}
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I can't fix your problem but I have added a better MWE which unambiguously shows the problem.

Comment: With LuaLaTeX and Latin hyphenation, I get `vi-dē-rī
vi-de-ri
Vul-pēs
Vul-pes
Cā-seum
Ca-seum vi-dē-rī-vul-pē-scā-seum vi-de-ri-vul-pe-sca-seum`

Comment: By the way, the bit you found in the languages manual, saying that `ē=e` is only about sorting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the macrons to be recognized, you have to add them to the `characters` list in the pattern with `\definehyphenationfeatures`:

```
\language[la]
\setuphyphenation[method=traditional]
\definehyphenationfeatures
  [macrons]
  [characters={āēī}]
\sethyphenationfeatures[macrons]
\starttext
\startlines
\hyphenatedword{vidērī}
\hyphenatedword{videri}
\hyphenatedword{Vulpēs}
\hyphenatedword{Vulpes}
\hyphenatedword{Cāseum}
\hyphenatedword{Caseum}
\hyphenatedword{vidērīvulpēscāseum}
\hyphenatedword{viderivulpescaseum}
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all very much, this wil absolutely improve my layout! Perhaps it wil be useful to add the code necessary when working in LaTeX. I believe the same problem occurs there.